# Button in the dropdown menu is not working in plolty, whenever i am clicking the data is not updating

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

Dropdown menu is not working in plolty, trying to plot Candle stick and bar plot, using two differnet dataset, i am using updatemenu, but whenever i am clicking on the button the plot candle stick is being updated but not volumne. Output- https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqggP.jpg, but when i click the button - https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ8hC.jpg
Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

inp30 = [{'time':"2022-01-06 12:30:00+00:00",'open':42663.81,'high':43019.10,'low':42679.31,'close':43136.87, 'momentum_normalized':552.457612 },
{'time':"2022-01-06 13:00:00+00:00",'open':43136.87,'high':43136.87,'low':42941.81,'close':42988.11, 'momentum_normalized':551.112364 },
{'time':"2022-01-06 13:30:00+00:00",'open':42988.11,'high':43160.16,'low':42946.19,'close':43153.66, 'momentum_normalized':573.398609 },
{'time':"2022-01-06 14:00:00+00:00",'open': 43153.66 ,'high':43153.66,'low':42870.81,'close':42870.81, 'momentum_normalized':466.704634}]
inp60 = [{'time':"2022-01-06 13:00:00+00:00",'open':42663.81,'high':43019.10,'low':42679.31,'close':43136.87, 'momentum_normalized':552.457612 },
{'time':"2022-01-06 14:00:00+00:00",'open': 43153.66 ,'high':43153.66,'low':42870.81,'close':42870.81, 'momentum_normalized':466.704634}]

df30min = pd.DataFrame(inp30)
df60min = pd.DataFrame(inp60)

pio.renderers.default = 'browser'

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2,cols=1,shared_xaxes=True,vertical_spacing=0.03,
    subplot_titles=('OHLC', 'Volume'),row_width=[0.2, 0.7]
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Candlestick(
        x=df30min['time'],
        open=df30min['open'], high=df30min['high'],
        low=df30min['low'], close=df30min['close'],
        increasing_line_color= 'green', 
        decreasing_line_color= 'red',name='price'), 
        row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=df30min['time'], 
        y=df30min['momentum_normalized'],
        name='momentum',showlegend=False), 
        row=2, col=1
)


fig.update_layout(title = '60 Minute')
updatemenus = [{
    'buttons':[
        {'method':'update',
         'label':'30 Minute',
         'args':[{
             'open':[list(df30min.open)],'high': [list(df30min.high)],
             'low': [list(df30min.low)],'close': [list(df30min.close)],
             'x':[list(df30min.time)],'visible':True},
         {'title':'30 Minute'}]},

        {'method':'update',
         'label':'60 Minute',
         'args':[{
             'open':[list(df60min.open)],'high': [list(df60min.high)],
             'low': [list(df60min.low)],'close': [list(df60min.close)],
             'x':[list(df60min.time)]},
         {'title':'60 Minute'}]},
    ],
    'type':'dropdown',
    'direction': 'down',
    'showactive': True}]
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus,title_text='Chart2 CandelStick', title_x=0.5)
fig.update(layout_xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **method** should be **relayout** for this use case as you are modifying layout
2. the annotations need to a a **list** of **dict**.  Not a **dict** with a list of **x** and **y**

Have synthesized data to make this a MWE.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df30min = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.date_range("1-jan-2022", freq="30Min", periods=10),
    data=np.random.randint(500, 1000, 10),
    columns=["surplus"],
)
df60min = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.date_range("1-jan-2022", freq="60Min", periods=5),
    data=np.random.randint(500, 1000, 5),
    columns=["surplus"],
)


plot = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Scatter(x=list(df30min.index), y=list(df30min.surplus), name="surplus")]
)

a_mins = [
    dict(
        x=x,
        y=y.surplus,
        text="30mins Button",
        xref="x",
        yref="y",
    )
    for x, y in df30min.iterrows()
]

b_mins = [
    dict(
        x=x,
        y=y.surplus,
        text="60mins Button",
        xref="x",
        yref="y",
    )
    for x, y in df60min.iterrows()
]

plot.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            active=0,
            buttons=list(
                [
                    dict(
                        label="30",
                        method="relayout",
                        args=[{"title": "30", "annotations": a_mins}],
                    ),
                    dict(
                        label="60",
                        method="relayout",
                        args=[{"title": "60", "annotations": b_mins}],
                    ),
                ]
            ),
        )
    ]
)

plot.show()
```

Comment: , First of all thanks for the help, but i am expecting the output like this https://imgur.com/a/SK7gauM

Comment: I've had to completely guess what your data might be as you have not provided samples in the question.  I have no idea in df30min and df60min are off same underlying data with different resampling size.  define your data and I can amend.  given the data generated is random, your images are exactly what I get so meet your exceptions !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70753935/how-is-the-updatemenu-related-to-add-trace-in-plolty i have put a different question with proper dataset and output i am expecting and the error i am getting pls, help me solve it.

Comment: why didn't you update this question with data?  that new question isn't really valid,  you have not shown what you have tried at all.  On SO we're here to help not to do your coding....  I've voted to close this question,  clearly it's not well formed and I have completely wasted my time trying to help

Comment: Apologies but I am new to stackoverflow and have started my coding journey few months ago. I understand how to post a question now and have updated it accordinly.

Thank you for your help nonetheless.